# what's the string length limit of jenkins string parameter

Tags: jenkins

Now I create a jenkins job with string parameter, and this parameter is come from the upstream job.
I just want to know is there any limit about the length of the string parameter, because this info is get from upstream job and it cloud be a very long string

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm curious about the answer ot this too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe noone really provides an answer since there is no reason to limit the underlying technology. So let's look at that:

1. Java
   Java itself seems quite capable of running big strings, but how big is big actually? There is a quite good response in [How many characters can a Java String have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have)
2. Jetty/Webserver
   Jenkins is a web application, and as such runs with the embedded jetty or requires to be deployed on some JEE Servlet Container. They, similar as Java do not apply specific limitiations.
3. HTTP Protocol
   Regardless of whether you run Jenkins through HTTP or HTTPS, that technology does not limit request or parameter size per specification. On the other hand and mostly for availability and security reasons limits are configured. Depending on the servlet container you use check that configuration. One reason to limit those sizes is to mitigate Slowloris attacks.
4. Client Browser
   A lot of browsers have configured limits such as [Maximum length of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).

It may seem the strictest limitations come from browser implementations, although I believe as a person responsible for Jenkins operations you want to limit HTTP request and parameter size on the server side. An example of how to do it is in [Configure max post size for a external webapp in jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181892/configure-max-post-size-for-a-external-webapp-in-jetty)